# Mapping duplicate values from Map against the keys in which they are found

Tags: java, hashmap

What I have is:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Shop1", "Product1");
map.put("Shop2", "Product2");
map.put("Shop3", "Product1");
map.put("Shop4", "Product2");
map.put("Shop5", "Product3");
```

What I want is:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
```

Wherein `result` contains:

Product1 -> Shop1,Shop3

Product2 -> Shop2,Shop4

Here Product1 is found at multiple times in shops Shop1 & Shop3 and Product2 is found multiple times in shops Shop2 & Shop4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to invert the map (values become keys and keys get grouped by old values). There should be libraries that do that, but a sample solution with streams:

```
result = map.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(e -> Collections.frequency(map.values(), e.getValue()) > 1)
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
```

Comment: This works for the most part just that it also gives Shop3 -> Product5 wherein Product5 occurs in just 1 shop and not multiple.

Comment: @ParagKadam Huh? The result I get when I print out result is: `{Product3=[Shop5], Product1=[Shop1, Shop3], Product2=[Shop4, Shop2]}`. Which looks correct.

Comment: Product3=[Shop5] shouldn't be in the result as it occurs in only Shop5, if it occurred at more than 1 shop then it should have been included in the result.

Comment: @ParagKadam Just add a filter before collecting, to include only duplicate values. something like `.stream().filter(e -> Collections.frequency(map.values(), e.getValue()) > 1).collect(Collectors.groupingBy....`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Guava's Multimap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Shop1", "Product1");
map.put("Shop2", "Product2");
map.put("Shop3", "Product1");
map.put("Shop4", "Product2");
map.put("Shop5", "Product3");

final Multimap<String, String> shopToProduct = Multimaps.forMap(map), productToShop = HashMultimap.create();

Multimaps.invertFrom(shopToProduct, productToShop);

// Prints the output you want
productToShop.asMap().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

// You can also get the backing map, but ideally use the Multimap abstraction
final Map<String, Collection<String>> backingMap = productToShop.asMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the `distinct` values first. After that, you can iterate through each value and search for their  `key` on the map, whenever you find a `key` you just put them into a `list`.

```
List<String> list = map.values().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()); //Collecting the distinct values
```

```
for (String value : list) {  //iterating through each key
    List<String> temp =  map.entrySet()
             .stream()
             .filter(entry -> value.equals(entry.getValue())) //filtering out similar entries
             .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
     result.put(value, temp);
 }
 System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Guava's [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to achieve this, however you'd need to invert the map.

```java
Multimap<String, String> map = HashMultimap.create();
map.put("Product1", "Shop1");
map.put("Product2", "Shop2");
map.put("Product2", "Shop1");
map.put("Product2", "Shop4");
map.put("Product3", "Shop5");
System.out.println(map.get("Product2")); // [Shop4, Shop1, Shop2]
```

Alternatively, if you'd prefer not to invert the original map - you can use a `Map<String, List<String>` (Or combine the following solution with the `Multimap` above) and add records with `computeIfAbsent`, then invert the map to get the values you want.

```java
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.computeIfAbsent("Shop1", (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Product1");
        map.computeIfAbsent("Shop2", (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Product2");
        map.computeIfAbsent("Shop3", (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Product1");
        map.computeIfAbsent("Shop4", (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Product2");
        map.computeIfAbsent("Shop5", (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add("Product3");
        // Invert the map
        Map<String, List<String>> invertedMap = map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(HashMap::new, (m, entry) -> {
                    entry.getValue().forEach((value) -> {
                        m.computeIfAbsent(value, (x) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey());
                    });
                }, Map::putAll);

        System.out.println(invertedMap); // {Product3=[Shop5], Product1=[Shop1, Shop3], Product2=[Shop4, Shop2]}
```